# wordpress posts not showing in frontend or backend

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed a new wordpress blog today (v3.4.2, Windows 2008 R2, IIS7.5, SQL Server 2008 R2). I have already done this several times, and I have never had this happen before.

When I create a new post and publish it, everything looks fine. When I go to view it through the link in the edit post page, everything looks good. Then I open the blog homepage and I don't see the post in the latest posts. When I go back in to wp-admin I see that there is (1) post in "all posts", but the list is empty.

I tried creating a second post, and when I view it from the editing page, I can see it and the one I "lost" before. I tried to see maybe there was a difference in the URLs, but they are the same.

Anyone seen this before? It is driving me insane.
I tried turning off all plugins and also switching to another theme, and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently, due to some regex issue in the abstraction plugin, mysql's limit was not being translated to sql server's top.

Found the solutions here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51134/dashboard-says-no-posts-found-even-though-there-are-some-posts

Give credit where credit is due :)